# Hidden input for Dictionary<string, string> in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary, hidden-field

I need to get my model properties in Post action, so need to hidden element for them, but I have a problem with type of `Dictionary <string, string>`. this is My model:

```
public class ViewModel{
 ...
 public ViewPart ViewPart { get; set; }
}

public class ViewPart {
 ...
 public Dictionary<string, string> Flags { get; set; }
}
```

And My Controller:

```
Dictionary<string, string> flags = new Dictionary<string, string>();
flags.Add("kind", "Edit");
flags.Add("Command", "Save");
ViewModel model = new ViewModel(){ Flags  = flags };
return View(model);
```

In View:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ViewPart.Flags) { 
 <input type="hidden" id="ViewPart_Flags_@(item.Key)" value="@item.Value" name="ViewPart.Flags[@(item.Key)]" />
}
```

Also I try This one :

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ViewPart.Flags) { 
  @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item)
}
```

**Update**
Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(ViewModel model){
  //model.ViewPart.Flags is null
}
```

But in Post action the `Flags` is Always null, why? where is my fault? Is there any better way to pass variables from View To Action?

Comment: What does the Post action look like, does it receive the Flags model like `public ActionResult Something(ViewPart viewPart)`?

Comment: @Garrett Fogerlie I Update the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two hidden fields one for the `Key` and one for the `Value` if you want to modelbind to a dictionary:

```
var index = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.ViewPart.Flags)
{

    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Key" 
                         name="ViewPart.Flags[@(index)].Key"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Value" 
                         name="ViewPart.Flags[@(index)].Value"/>

    index++;
}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Note, you will be also need a running index to make the model binder happy.

Or if you don't want to have a running you can solve with an addtional hidden `Index` field:

```
foreach (var item in Model.ViewPart.Flags)
{

    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Key" 
                         name="ViewPart.Flags.Index"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Key" 
                         name="ViewPart.Flags[@(item.Key)].Key" />
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Value" 
                         name="ViewPart.Flags[@(item.Key)].Value" />
}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

You can find a lots of info about modelbinding with collections in this two article:

- [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)
- [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Change your post action to this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(ViewModel model, ViewPart viewPart)
{
    model.ViewPart.Flags = viewPart.Flags;
}
```

and in the view use

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ViewPart.Flags) { 
  @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item)
}
```

If this doesn't work, check the source of the rendered HTML and see if the the Hidden information is rendered. I'm not sure if `@Html.HiddenFor` will work with a `Dictionary` you may need to write it out like you had done previously if it doesn't.